# Can there be an alternate anchor link for a video which doesnt get loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, video

I have a very strange question. In my html code for image and video gallery, I have used 'a' tag which opens a popup window and plays a video. Everything is working fine but it is bugging me when I think 'what if the video doesnt get loaded? it would show a black screen as there is no alternate image'. So I was thinking of ways that if a video is not loaded then an image will be shown. I think this can be done with the help of Javascript but I dont know how. the code is like this:
 
The image tag in this code is a thumbnail, where the user clicks and a popup appears.

Comment: <a class="popup" href="video_4.mp4"><img src="img_8.jpg" height="150px" width="250px" alt="Editor Reel"/></a>

Answer (score 0):

You can set a "backup" image as the background of the popup window. You can do that via CSS https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/background

You can even use CSS to display a pseudo element which contains text (see ::before)

Comment: The class you should add CSS to is .popup